# Como recuperar um soapObject de um retorno do webservice

Tags: java, android, soap

```
 androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION4, envelope);
            SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

            System.out.println(result.getProperty("nmConsultor"));
            return result.toString();
```

No caso eu gostaria de recuperar as properties contidas em meu retorno...

Alguem pode me ajudar??

Comment: Se possível, use um REST Service com JSon, já que cada envelope SOAP é muito grande e pode consumir bastante tráfego de dados no Android.

Comment: o problema é que o webservice é criado de fora da empresa... aí não tenho como opinar =/

Comment: eu entendo, de qualquer forma esse seria um bom argumento.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando a biblioteca do ksoap2 v2.5.8, faço dessa forma:

```
public static String conectWs(String URL, String NAMESPACE, String METHOD_NAME, String strDataXmt, String param) throws Exception{

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = null;
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE , METHOD_NAME);

    request.addProperty(param, strDataXmt);
    //androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.call(NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME, envelope);
    Object results = (Object) envelope.getResponse();

    return results.toString();
}
```

Depois, para ler essa String de resultado como um Xml, eu faço esse parse:

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
 DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  
 Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(stringDeResultado)));  

 doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
 NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("suaTag");
```

Comment: Obrigado Brother, e no caso de vir um XML de resposta... eu não estou conseguindo parsear, pois esta vindo em formato String, aí não consigo recuperar as properties... Obrigado pela atenção

Comment: Editei o post, vê se é isso que você estava querendo

Comment: Eu Consegui fazer, mas esta com retornando esse erro...


Unexpected token (position:TEXT anyType{GestorWe...@1:163 in java.io.StringReader@41750d08) 

o que será que pode ser? desculpe o incomodo, nunca mexi com XML e Webservice... Muito Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: tem como você me mandar o conteúdo da String no momento do parse?

Comment: string = anyType{GestorWebServices=anyType{cdRetorno=0; dsRetorno=anyType{}; cdConsultor=7; nmConsultor=Ediana Frainer Mazotto; cdHash=010200020007008307042014205205; }; }

Comment: Rapaz, esse retorno aí não é um XML não. Por isso o erro.

Comment: no serviço ta dizendo que vem xml 
http://gestorweb.guiafacil.com/gestorwebservices/GestorWebServices.asmx?op=AutenticarTablet

Comment: esse link que vc me mandou não tá abrindo, parece que por conta de timeout. Ele está em modo de debug?

Comment: tenta esse aqui

http://gestorweb.guiafacil.com/gestorwebservices/GestorWebServices.asmx

Comment: nao tá funfando essa url nao...

Comment: muito estranho to mexendo nela aqui agora e ta funfando

Comment: http://gestorweb.guiafacil.com/gestorwebservices/GestorWebServices.asmx

estranho pois aqui funfa e ja é de fora isso